# Base64 content in pseudoelement isn't displayed in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, flexbox

I created a custom checkbox element using a ::before pseudoelement for a label, as it should be. Then I realized that it actually should have a check mark by the design specification, and so I added it to content attribute. Through a postprocessor it got encodeed as base64. It works really well on firefox - unfortunately, on chrome it doesn't show up at all

Expected result (screenshot from firefox):

[image: Expected result]

What we get:

[image: Result on chrome]

After a bit of fiddling it seems that it's all about the ::before pseudoelement being displayed as flex (but this way I can position it properly).

Do you have any idea why it works like that - or how can I get around it?

Minimal working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmyEpo?editors=1111

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="checkbox__input">
  <label class="checkbox__label">Label</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox__label {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox__label::before {
  content: '';
  width: .8em;
  height: .8em;
  border: 3px solid;
  margin-right: .5em;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .3em;
  border-radius: 50%;

  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2em #000;
  content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1MTIgNTEyIj48cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjRkZGIiBkPSJNMTczLjg5OCA0MzkuNDA0bC0xNjYuNC0xNjYuNGMtOS45OTctOS45OTctOS45OTctMjYuMjA2IDAtMzYuMjA0bDM2LjIwMy0zNi4yMDRjOS45OTctOS45OTggMjYuMjA3LTkuOTk4IDM2LjIwNCAwTDE5MiAzMTIuNjkgNDMyLjA5NSA3Mi41OTZjOS45OTctOS45OTcgMjYuMjA3LTkuOTk3IDM2LjIwNCAwbDM2LjIwMyAzNi4yMDRjOS45OTcgOS45OTcgOS45OTcgMjYuMjA2IDAgMzYuMjA0bC0yOTQuNCAyOTQuNDAxYy05Ljk5OCA5Ljk5Ny0yNi4yMDcgOS45OTctMzYuMjA0LS4wMDF6Ii8+PC9zdmc+);
}

.checkbox__input {
  display: none;
}
```

Edit: The SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="#FFF" d="M173.898 439.404l-166.4-166.4c-9.997-9.997-9.997-26.206 0-36.204l36.203-36.204c9.997-9.998 26.207-9.998 36.204 0L192 312.69 432.095 72.596c9.997-9.997 26.207-9.997 36.204 0l36.203 36.204c9.997 9.997 9.997 26.206 0 36.204l-294.4 294.401c-9.998 9.997-26.207 9.997-36.204-.001z"/></svg>
```

Comment: can you share the initial SVG that you converted to base64 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif added in the edit

Comment: You can add the check by a `:before` or `:after` by rotating it and just color the `border`

Answer (score 2):

It works if you add `width` and `height` to your SVG:

```
content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' viewBox='0 -50 512 512'%3E %3Cpath fill='%23FFF' d='M173.898 439.404l-166.4-166.4c-9.997-9.997-9.997-26.206 0-36.204l36.203-36.204c9.997-9.998 26.207-9.998 36.204 0L192 312.69 432.095 72.596c9.997-9.997 26.207-9.997 36.204 0l36.203 36.204c9.997 9.997 9.997 26.206 0 36.204l-294.4 294.401c-9.998 9.997-26.207 9.997-36.204-.001z'/%3E %3C/svg%3E");
```

*(Changed from Base64-encoding to [URL-encoding](https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/doMoML) for easier editing)*

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/YJddQq